# What does "pa k kieres saber eso jaja saludos" mean?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos

I keep seeing the phrase "pa k kieres saber eso jaja saludos" on Twitter, and I know it's definitely slang/a meme but I can't figure out what it means. I'd appreciate any help, ¡gracias!

[Here](http://www.buzzfeed.com/javieraceves/este-es-el-nuevo-meme-que-esta-desquiciando-al-internet#.vy5Kbpm7VR) are some examples of it being used.

Comment: it's kinda like "what do you want to know that for haha regards".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Written with normal spelling, it reads as follows:

> ¿Para qué quieres saber eso?  Jaja.  Saludos.

In other words:

> Whither dost thou want to know that?  Ha.  Farewell.

Okay, that's a bit formal.  It's more like

> Y u wanna know? Lol kbai

Comment: XD LOL ROFL LMAO

Comment: +1 for kbai lol

Comment: =D =D very good answer!!!

Comment: This is the most elegant way of saying "It's a meme" without actually saying it is... love it.

Answer (score 4):

Translation:

> "Why do u want to know it? haha regards"

It was a meme born by Yahoo Answers, this user asked for a question of philosophy: http://prntscr.com/9o1pp9 (about books)

and other user answered : http://prntscr.com/9o1q4n

Comment: thats the stuff memes are made of. Notice the amount of upvotes for the "lol kbai" equivalent answer, totally out of place in a question asking for Nietsche's best reference on Nihilism.. I ask my self, why did the guy wan t to know that, anyways?

Answer (score -1):

its an screenshot from a facebook messenger conversation, where a girl ask a guy "Why did he kissed another girl"and he respond with that quote...

and its funny cause you dont answer a mad girl with

"Why do you want to know that..

haha Greetings""

:)